# Switching git Repository on Live Server

Tags: laravel, git

I have a situation here.

Let say I have a website alpha.com and I was using `git ftp push` command to push the code to live server form Repository **apple**.

For some reason, I have to change the repository to **Orange** (cloned from apple).

Now what needs to be done in order to change repository on the live server from **apple** to **Orange**.
I do not want to do `git init` once again on the live server.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
TR